# Signed and unsigned integers?

Tags: integer, unsigned, signed

Could someone please explain the two to me because I have to give an explanation of them both in my assignment.

I know what a normal integer is of course and have used the following to describe it:

"An integer is a whole number which can be positive, negative and zero but it cannot have decimal points."

But I'm just not sure about signed and unsigned.

Thanks

Comment: "Signed" includes the sign (negative or positive). "Unsigned" does not — can only be non-negative. You could probably find a good amount of information on Wikipedia or something.

Answer (score 8):

In most languages when you declare an integer, you are declaring a signed integer.  If you want to declare an unsigned integer you have to specifically tell the compiler.  e.g. in c#

```
int a; // Signed int
uint b; // Unsigned int.
```

The difference is that in a signed int, one of the bits is used to indicate if the number is positive or negative.  In and unsigned int, that bit is used to hold a value.  The effect is that you can hold twice the absolute values in an unsigned in as you can in a signed int.  Or more plainly, the range of the C# integer is -2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647 while the range of the uint is 0 to 4,294,967,295.  Both data types are 32 bit datatypes.

Answer (score 2):

The difference between a signed and unsigned integer is that one byte of the integer is required to hold the sign.

For instance, with two binary digits you can have the following:

```
Base 2   Base 10
00       0
01       1
10       2
11       3
```

However, if we take the first digit to mean negative (0) or positive (1)

```
Base 2   Base 10
01       -1
00       0
10       1
11       2
```

Or, if we wanted 1 to be negatiave, and 0 to be positive:

```
Base 2   Base 10
01       1
00       0
10       -1
11       -2
```

For further reading, check out the Wikepedia article on [Two's compliment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twos_Compliment)

Comment: "one byte of the integer is used.." should be "one **bit** of the integer is used.."

Answer (score -1):

Generally when you say int, it is signed int.
(signed) int has a range of -32768 - 32767 
But unsigned int has a range of 0 - 65535

An Unsigned Variable Type of int can hold zero and positive numbers but a signed int holds negative, zero or positive numbers.

Comment: That's true for a 16 bit but inaccurate for 32, 64 bit etc. If you amend then my -1 will become a +1.